# Paste html form data into url

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, forms

Assuming i have resource with 2 methods :show and :index. I need :index contain simple form with text field and submit button, when user insert data into text field, this data must be  inserted into url as :id of resource for :show method.

for example page url looks like `/s` and when user type 123 into field in the form and press submit he must be redirected to `/s/123`. Can it be done with rails or html forms ?

Comment: LoL, i just didnt know that answers must be accepted. And i think i must use javascript here, but i do not want to. My question is to do that with html form or with some rails helper.

Comment: You cannot dynamically generate a URL with the structure `/s/:id` where `:id` is some integer value with HTML only. The closes you can come is to make the `<form>` a `GET` request, and give the field a `name="id"` attribute. This would create a URL like `/s?id=123`. If you want to make the URL `/s/123` you'll have to use Javascript. Rails can't help you because the functionality you're looking for is client-side

Comment: I thought so, i just hoping that javascript can be generated with rails helpers. Not manually

Answer (score 0):

Do you mid having s?id=123 I can't comment that is why I am posting if so then use this code

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" name="id">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Remember always the name of the textbox will appear in the textbox now it is id so it should be `s?id=value` and when the name is changed for example to usd then the url will be `s?usd=value.`

Remember to perform a function with these urls use the below code.

```
if($_GET['textbox_name'] == true){//things to do}
```